# Cannot reuse audio element

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to re-use an audio element however I get the following error in Chrome:

> (index):52 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute
>   'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': HTMLMediaElement already
>   connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode.

```
window.audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

var sourceNode
var scripNode

function create() {
  scriptNode = window.audioContext.createScriptProcessor(4096);
  sourceNode = window.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById('audio'));

  sourceNode.connect(scriptNode);
  scriptNode.connect(window.audioContext.destination);
}

function destroy() {
  sourceNode.disconnect();
  scriptNode.disconnect();
}

create();

setTimeout(function() {
  destroy();
  create();
}, 200);
```

What is the proper way to clean up using web audio so that a mediaelement can be re-used?

Answer (score 0):

You are not destroying the node sourceNode you are just disconnecting them. Why not just reconnect the audio node, since you're using the same one, to the other audio graph or what ever it is you're trying to do?

Otherwise you can delete the HTML audio element, recreate it and then reconnect that way.

Comment: How do I "destroy"  a node?

Comment: In short, you can't. JavaScript should destroy them if there is no reference to them anymore. However the actual HTML element will probably still hold a reference to the javascript node so likely it will not get destroyed that way.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a longstanding issue in Chrome.  I think there are ways around this, but you don't show what you really want to do, so it's hard to say what the appropriate workaround is.

Comment: Chrome really should fix this.

Comment: What I really want to do is what I do in the example :).

Comment: If you want to convince some one to maybe fix it, you're not doing a very good job with a toy demo as the application you really want.  Explain why you need to re-use a mediaelement in a real application.